# App crashes after installing sdkbox(chartboost plugin) on android v2.3.6

Tags: android, c++, cocos2d-x

after installing sdkbox and importing chartboost plugin, the app crashes on startup
exactly at loading libcocos2dcpp.so

i get a fatal signal 4 SIGILL error

ndk-stack reveals the following

```
adb logcat | ndk-stack -sym /home/elmagnifico/Desktop/cocos2d-x-3.9/test2/proj.android/obj/local/armeabi
    ********** Crash dump: **********
    Build fingerprint: 'samsung/GT-S5830i/GT-S5830i:2.3.6/GINGERBREAD/JPLK1:user/release-keys'
    pid: 15452, tid: 15452 >>> org.cocos2dx.test2 <<<
    signal 4 (SIGILL), code 1 (ILL_ILLOPC), fault addr 8111a97c
    Stack frame #00 pc 0011a97c /mnt/asec/org.cocos2dx.test2-2/lib/libcocos2dcpp.so: Routine GLOBAL__subI_CCData.cpp at /private/var/jenkins/.jenkins/jobs/_release_1.5.2/workspace/csc/protocols/proj.android/jni/../../share/CCData.cpp:92
    Crash dump is completed
```

I tried with another android version 4.4 ... and it works fine

I am using v0.5.8.12 and cocos2dx v3.9

here is Application.mk

```
APP_STL := gnustl_static

APP_CPPFLAGS := -frtti -DCC_ENABLE_CHIPMUNK_INTEGRATION=1 -std=c++11 -fsigned-char
APP_LDFLAGS := -latomic

ifeq ($(NDK_DEBUG),1)
APP_CPPFLAGS += -DCOCOS2D_DEBUG=1
APP_OPTIM := debug
else
APP_CPPFLAGS += -DNDEBUG
APP_OPTIM := release
endif
APP_PLATFORM := android-9
```